# Schengen Visa - Main destination

Tags: schengen, france, schengen-visas, belgium

My friends and I are visiting the Schengen area, specifically Italy (1.5 days, 2 nights), France (3 days, 3 nights) and Belgium (3.5 days, 3 nights), in that order.

*Assuming that the duration of the longest stay is counted in nights*, it would be either France or Belgium, is there any way to specify Belgium as my "main" destination? Or since we're going to France first, should we apply for a visa at the French consulate?

Comment: The Visa Code just says "length of stay". If there's doubt, why not count in hours rather than round to whole days/ nights?

Comment: If no main destination can be identified, you're supposed to apply with your country of first entry, which would be Italy not France.